# How to use Lookup Field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I have a custom LWC Page which is used as Public site.

On this lwc, I have a form to populate data in `contact` object. I have one custom object called `school` this is the look up filter field in Contact object.

When i tried to Use the School look up filter in my page, It doesn't display anything in the page.  Is there anything which i have missed.Please  guide me.

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
 <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                                    <label for="fieldid">School</label>
                                                    <lightning-input-field id="schoolId" required={required}
                                                        variant="label-hidden" field-name="School__c"
                                                        value={schoolValue} onchange={handleChange}>
                                                    </lightning-input-field>
                                                </div>
 </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Comment: Does the "Guest User" have Field Level Security set up for this field? Do they have access to the School__c object? What about the Contact object? Why are you overriding the label and providing your own?

Comment: Yes Guest User have Read and Edit access for `School` Object Fields, I can able to create and Edit the other fields in Contact object.

Comment: Are you trying to use lookup field in the component? lookup field is not available as out of box in lightning component (aura and lwc both). You may need to create your own custom lookup

Answer (score 6):

You need a custom lookup component. Below is one of the best open source implementation so far:

https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

Comment: Documentation is a lot on the above github article but lacking the quality/point. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the first result I get when I search on the web, I want to point out that salesforce just implemented a solution for this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-picker/documentation

In case the link is not working anymore, I quote:

The **lightning-record-picker** component allows you to search for a list of Salesforce Records that match search input. It uses the GraphQL wire adapter to search for records, displays the records, and allows the user to select a record.

This example creates a record picker component that searches for Account objects.

```
<lightning-record-picker
    label="Accounts"
    placeholder="Search Accounts..."
    object-api-name="Account"
>
</lightning-record-picker>
```

**Filter**
The filter attribute specifies which records the component lists in the record picker. The value for filter is an object with a single property, criteria. criteria is an array with a list of filter criteria objects and an optional filterLogic property.

This example filters records where the "Site" field equals "Grenoble" or null, "SerialNumber__c" doesn't start with "PRD-", and "Status" doesn't equal "Closed".

```
const filter = {
    criteria: [
        {
            fieldPath: 'Site',
            operator: 'eq',
            value: `Grenoble`,
        },
        {
            fieldPath: 'Site',
            operator: 'eq',
            value: null,
        },
        {
            fieldPath: 'Status',
            operator: 'ne',
            value: 'Closed',
        },
        {
            fieldPath: 'SerialNumber__c',
            operator: 'like',
            value: 'PRD-%',
        },
        filterLogic: '(1 OR 2) AND NOT(4) AND 3'
    ];
}
```

```
<lightning-record-picker object-api-name="Account" filter={filter}>
</lightning-record-picker>
```

**Filter Logic**
filterLogic is a string that defines logic for the set of filter criteria objects in the criteria array. If filterLogic is undefined, all criteria are applied with an AND logical operator by default. Valid operators are AND, OR, and NOT. AND has higher precedence than OR. Parentheses are supported.

**Filter Criterion**
The filter criterion object defines the criteria for individual filters. These filters can be combined using logical operators in the criteria array.

The filter criterion object contains the following properties.

| NAME | TYPE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fieldPath (required) | string | The name of the field in the API to filter on. Spanning relationships is supported at one level (Account.Phone). |
| operator (required) | string | The filter operator. Can be any of the supported types and operators listed in the table below. |
| value (required) | string | The value to filter against. If using a date filter, see the following table for accepted values. |